# How to swap audio streams in a video

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, video-processing

I have a situation where I need my video to have the first stream video and second one audio. Because if the first stream of the video comes to us as Audio our app fails. So in order for me to fix the issue is to swap the streams. I already was capable to swap the streams by using **ffmpeg** by using this command `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -map 0:v:0? -map 0:a:1? -map 0:a:0? -c copy output.mp4` but unfortunately there are some things that we can't use ffmpeg in our project for the moment. So my question is: is any way to do this swap natively (without using 3rd party library)?

This is how I tried to solve the issue but I failed (it still giving me audio stream first before video):

```
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: source, options: nil)
    
    let composition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    let videoTimeRange: CMTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: avAsset.duration)
    
    let compositionVideoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let sourceVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack? = avAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first
    compositionVideoTrack!.preferredTransform = sourceVideoTrack!.preferredTransform
    _ = try? compositionVideoTrack!.insertTimeRange(videoTimeRange, of: sourceVideoTrack!, at: CMTime.zero)
    
    let compositionAudioTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let sourceAudioTrack: AVAssetTrack? = avAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first
    _ = try? compositionAudioTrack!.insertTimeRange(videoTimeRange, of: sourceAudioTrack!, at: CMTime.zero)                

    
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else {
        completionHandler(nil)
        return
    }
    
    let destination = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("video-\(UUID().uuidString).mp4")
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destination)

    exportSession.outputURL = destination
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    
    let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, preferredTimescale: 1000) // this preferredTimescale was 0 I edited to 1000 and now it works.
    let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start: start, duration: avAsset.duration)
    exportSession.timeRange = range


    exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
        switch exportSession.status {
        case .failed:                
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        case .cancelled:
            print("Export canceled")
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        case .completed:                
            print("Export completed!")
            print(exportSession.outputURL?.absoluteString)
            completionHandler(exportSession.outputURL?.absoluteString)
            return
            default: break
        }
    })
```

**EDITED:** I Solved the issue by setting the **preferredTimescale** to 1000 instead of 0

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your `ffmpeg` command can be rendered in `AVFoundation` as

```
let inputAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputUrl)
let outputAsset = AVMutableComposition()
        
// Output video track
let inVideoTrack = inputAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
let outVideoTrack = outputAsset.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
try! outVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(inVideoTrack.timeRange, of: inVideoTrack, at: .invalid)
// End output video track

// Output audio track
let inAudioTrack = inputAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first!
let outAudioTrack = outputAsset.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
try! outAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(inAudioTrack.timeRange, of: inAudioTrack, at: .invalid)
// End output audio track

try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputUrl)
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: outputAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!
exportSession.outputURL = outputUrl
exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4

exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
    if exportSession.status == .failed {
        print("passthru export failed: \(String(describing: exportSession.error))")
    }
    assert(exportSession.status == .completed)
}
```

The important ingredients are the order in which you add the output tracks (video vs audio) and exporting the result using a pass through export session, so that no transcoding takes place.

Comment: I already did this, but its giving me always the first stream audio. If you have ffmpeg installed on your machine you can test by using this command ffprobe -show-streams yourVideo.mp4 and you will see that this block of code will set the first stream audio not video.

Comment: `-show_streams` is telling me that this works with my input - index 0 is audio before and video after.